# Is there a way to limit user to click a jbutton once in java

Tags: java, swing

If in a card game i only want to the user to click the deal button once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the button on the click.

```
   b1.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: would b1. be the button name?